# Xcode: Get name from UIButton name

Tags: xcode, casting, integer, sender

I would like get the integer from the name of a UIButton.

The UIButton's name is "Button11", and I would like my integer therefore like to be 11.

Can anybody please tell me how to do that?

I "already" have the following code:

```
-(IBAction)processButtonUpInside:(id)sender
{
     UIButton *nButton (UIButton*)sender;
     integer_t nInt = ... //I am not perfectly sure if I should use "integer_t" 
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: looks like you have created this button in Interface Builder.. if so, who don't you keep tags of buttons and simply take the  tag values instead of fetching the values through names..

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea, but I would anyway like to know how this could be done with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use tag instead of name for your need.

```
[aButton setTag:11];


-(IBAction)processButtonUpInside:(id)sender
{
     UIButton *nButton = (UIButton*)sender;
     int nInt =  nButton.tag;
}
```

But, if you still need the integer in name, then set the button name like this:@"13button"

Now you can get the integer like this.

```
[nButton.titleLabel intValue];//13
```

**EDIT:**

Button name is @"Button13".

```
   NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSString *newString = [[nButton.titleLabel.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[numbers invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
//newString = 13
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you. But what would be the best way to "extract" the integer from the string anyway if it was formed like "Button11"?

Comment: Corrected my answer It's not nButton.titleLabel, it's nButton.titleLabel.text